# Quasar QStepper keep-alive not working in vertical mode

Tags: node.js, vue.js, quasar

While developing an App with Quasar/Vue I noticed that the state of a QStepper's QStep is lost when the Stepper is set to vertical mode. The Problem does not occure in horizontal mode.

Here is a short example Code:

```
<q-stepper
        v-model="step"
        animated
        color="primary"
        keep-alive
//toggle vertical mode
        vertical
      >
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5c6pyvdg/2/

If the Stepper is set to horizontal Mode, Pictures added to the uploader will get shown after switching the step forth and back. When doing the same in vertical Mode, Pictures are gone...

I tried searching for something odd within the Quasar code, but was unable to find either a reference to the problem online, nor the problem itself.